# Want to open Xampp index.html on request Domain Name : helpdesk/cs changed from ip 172.16.172.17

Tags: html, apache, web-services, security, xampp

I have made a website with domain and path name **"helpdesk/cs/index.html"**
When i type the above address from ipad and windows computer browser by default set to http they show me the required page 
But when i type the same address it gives me error as attached snaps and by default in browser it is **https which doesn`t resolve the ip by typing ip it is reponding perfectly i want to access the local webpage with Domain Name.

I am Using Xampp Apache 2.4 webserver with html webpages .
Kindly resolve the issue as soon as possible**

[Doesn`t Repond to request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L17mb.jpg)

[Certificate Error Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWccM.jpg)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i sorted out the issue which i have posted the main issue was with the http port and https port difference .
I just configured the server for http request on port 80 on my system on windows firewall than i studied the difference https accept the request on port 443 so i configured the system for port 443 also and all the requests received on the domain is being responded

I just posted the answer so any other person who find`s the same problem may follow the above mentioned comments 
Thanks